# ASP.NET C# Display address details if logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my website i am trying to get my site to display the users address details if they are logged in  have tried a stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.showAddress
    @userid nvarchar(256)
AS
    SELECT Fullname, Address, County, Postcode FROM Addresses WHERE @userid = UserId
RETURN
```

But i get an area about expecting the user id? I have tried inserting through code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        SqlCommand oCMD = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection oCON = new SqlConnection();
        oCON.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
        oCON.Open();
        oCMD.Connection = oCON;
        oCMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        oCMD.CommandText = "showAddress";

        SqlDataReader oRDR = oCMD.ExecuteReader();
        oRDR.Read();
        txtName.Text = oRDR.GetString(oRDR.GetOrdinal("Fullname"));
        oCON.Close();
    }
}
```

But this doesnt work either for me. Is there some code that could be entered as something like:

txtPostcode.Text = "sql connection; Addresses; Fullname";

Any help or ADVICE is appreciated....

Answer (score 2):

In your C#, you need to add the @userid as a parameter to pass to the stored procedure.

```
oCMD.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userid", userid));
```

Obviously, you will need to get the userID from somewhere, such as the User.Identity object.

Comment: Hey,
I have added thie line to my code:
    'oCMD.Parameters.Add("@userid", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 256).Value = User.Identity.Name;'
But when i try run this and i get to my page with this code behind i Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.? So confused!!

Comment: I have figured out that my code in fact is working! BUT... The issue seems to be that when a user egisters for my site using the CreateUserWizard and this encrypts the username and password, so when my program looks into database for the username it finds the encrypted text and this oviously doesnt match! So i need to either decrypt the code or never encrypt as it goes into databse table! Hmmm...

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me you're not passing useid parameter to the stored procedure.

```
oCMD.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userId", User.UserId));//plz check the User object to find the id
```